# What are the necessary professions of an advanced society

Tags: society, humans, economy, civilization, tribes

In small villages, the jobs of individuals are quite well defined.
For a population of 100 people, the make up might be something like:

- 20    Children (not working)
- 15    Elderly (not working)
- 10    Farmers
- 10    Builders
- 10    Hunters
- 10    Craftsmen
- 5 Doctors
- 5 Cooks
- 10    Other resource gatherers
- 5 Some kind of royalty

What might the professions of an advanced society look like?

This is assuming a peaceful society (so no military needed, but still probably law enforcement) and only useful professions (sorry marketing and advertising)

Comment: How advanced? 1910? 1950? 2015? 2050?

Comment: What do you consider an advanced society? For example, the Romans had an advanced society for their time, although compared to us they were primitive.

Comment: Looking at the description reminds me of Banished, it's in the middle ages ?

Comment: From now to the next 20 or so years.
The bigger picture for this is in this world, people have shifted from being countries to instead being a thousand self governing, self sufficient cities of a million people each, where roles are stringently defined, essentially very large villiages

Comment: @Ellimist0 In that case I would think that modern professions would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Think Demolition Man type society where inefficiencies like toilet paper have been squeezed out. What are the truly necessary professions

Comment: 3100, end of cycle robot waste technician counselor .

Comment: Even small villages can have drastically different jobs that need to be filled. A fishing village, for example, will have very different jobs than one which relies on mining or a village of herders.

Comment: @Ellimist0 are you looking for a bullet point answer like your example with numbers? or are you looking for broad ideas of different occupations because I feel the latter is a bit too broad.

Comment: 100 is too small to be independent, it just **can't**. There are too many roles to be filled.

Comment: @Lohoris Cities have a million people. There are a thousand such cities. (At least that's how I read Ellimist0's comment.)

Comment: Who's looking after the children? Who's overseeing cleaning and maintenance?

Comment: @BrettFromLA in that case, it would be better to integrate that comment in the question

Comment: Not enough foodmakers, too many specialists. 5 doctors per 100 people? 10 builders? Who are they building for?

Comment: @Lohoris: Tribal societies could get by with even less, especially with much fewer specializations - everyone is a bit of a jack of all trades. Now, an *advanced* society can't get by with so little. The problem is where to put the line.

Comment: Why would the elderly not be working in your scenario? They can take care of those children that are too young to work (and children might start working far earlier than you might be used to because reasons), they can help with household chores, cooking, and a whole range of other things that do not require great physical prowess. In your list, you're basically saying that somewhere between 1/3 and 1/2 of the population *provides no value at all* to the rest of the population at any given time. I have serious doubts that something like that is realistic at all, especially with just 100 people.

Comment: 5 Royalty??? You only need a guillotine-maker to solve that issue

Comment: @SJuan76: I'd expect one 'leader' and two-three 'soldiers/policemen' plus a kind of 'treasurer'/'warehouseman' who'd comprise the "elite" of the village. Possibly some kind of priest too.

Comment: Downvoting because the OP describes one question and the comments from the author describe another. I'll retract it when the question is comprehensive.

Comment: SJuan76, what are the two questions?

Answer (score 4):

Healthcare Professionals will still be needed unless you're assuming your societies have advanced medicine to a point where they can simply immunize or genetically alter themselves to be resistant to any illness.  Even then you need someone to administer said alterations/immunizations.

Law Enforcement of some sort, as well as administrative leaders to decide what laws exist and how they should be enforced.

After that consider basic human needs: food/water/shelter.  These things will always be necessary regardless of advancement unless they alter physically/anatomically.  So farmers or some other form of food-providing occupation, as well as construction workers/architects who can design and create homes/businesses/etc.

Presumably you'll also have general resource acquisition positions (mining/timber gathering/etc) unless they've developed an automated workforce capable of doing that for them, in which case you can probably also strike construction workers and most other non-specialized manual labor from the list.

In truth the answer probably largely just depends on how much you want to accept automation will have advanced in your given time period.  You could probably relegate the majority of tasks (waste disposal, food generation, resource generation, luxuries creation, etc) to an automated workforce of some kind or other.  In this case you would probably only need a few specialists who can create/maintain/program various versions of said workforce.

**Edit**
You would also have to take into account whether these societies are starting from scratch, some middleground, or just evolving naturally.  If they begin from scratch then initially there will be a lot more manual-labor type jobs until they can acquire the resources to create their automated workers, then as creation of those whatever-you-want-to-call-them filled in, the human workforce could gradually be phased out to a life of luxury or however you want to spin it.

**Edit 2**
Inspired by Lohoris' comment: Communication is likely going to be harder to automate, and presumably it will be necessary to communicate not just within the society, but between these cities as well, if for no other reason than some materials (gathered/harvested through automation) may still only be available in certain areas, and thus trade will be required.  The mechanics of actually gathering and transporting materials between them could be automated as well, but the actual communication of how much, while possible perhaps to determine through algorithms, would most likely be left to humans to communicate properly.  In addition, if travel between them isn't restricted, each community will probably want a way to track movement of its citizens in other locations, and a way to share the various laws that may be relevant to outsiders, etc.

Comment: Don't forget transportations, communications, water&gas&electricity, etc.

Comment: Transportation can be automated as well (see recent news regarding self-driving cars, including the german self-driving 18-wheeler), and production of the self-driving/self-guided transportation could certainly be assigned to an automated workforce (i.e. assembly lines).  
Water/gas/electricity are just a matter of resource collection and proper processing as well, also "easily" (I used that term loosely) automated.  Communications is definitely a valid point, though, and also brings to mind that presumably diplomacy and trade between these societies would have to be facilitated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the global employment data of the United States - total number of registered employees per occupation or occupation group, extracted from [Bureau of Labor Statistics](http://www.bls.gov/data/) database.

Divide the numbers by 1351282.60 to get the number per 100 citizens. (of course they don't add up to 100 because of the overlaps - larger domains containing smaller ones. e.g. you get "retail sales workers" first, and then breakdown of various sales occupations; one employee appearing in several entries.

This doesn't contain unemployed and self-employed, but I believe finding these statistics should be relatively easy and they don't change the proportions of labor distribution by much.

(due to StackExchange limit of 30000 characters per answer, this needs to be broken into two posts; this contains the top half of the table.)

```
Area: National  
Period: May 2014    
Employment(1)   Occupation (SOC code)
135128260   All Occupations(000000)
21638470    Office and Administrative Support Occupations(430000)
14248470    Sales and Related Occupations(410000)
12277720    Food Preparation and Serving Related Occupations(350000)
9249310 Transportation and Material Moving Occupations(530000)
8934050 Production Occupations(510000)
8648920 Retail Sales Workers(412000)
8435780 Education Training and Library Occupations(250000)
7854380 Healthcare Practitioners and Technical Occupations(290000)
6883630 Food and Beverage Serving Workers(353000)
6828940 Business and Financial Operations Occupations(130000)
6741640 Management Occupations(110000)
5439370 Information and Record Clerks(434000)
5290270 Construction and Extraction Occupations(470000)
5244670 Installation Maintenance and Repair Occupations(490000)
4833840 Health Diagnosing and Treating Practitioners(291000)
4562160 Retail Salespersons(412031)
4371450 Building and Grounds Cleaning and Maintenance Occupations(370000)
4364160 Material Moving Workers(537000)
4264370 Business Operations Specialists(131000)
4154360 Personal Care and Service Occupations(390000)
4045100 Preschool Primary Secondary and Special Education School Teachers(252000)
3940500 Healthcare Support Occupations(310000)
3925760 Other Office and Administrative Support Workers(439000)
3915350 Construction Trades Workers(472000)
3880030 Material Recording Scheduling Dispatching and Distributing Workers(435000)
3834180 Computer and Mathematical Occupations(150000)
3741430 Motor Vehicle Operators(533000)
3692980 Computer Occupations(151100)
3649920 Secretaries and Administrative Assistants(436010)
3607860 Fast Food and Counter Workers(353020)
3519730 Laborers and Material Movers Hand(537060)
3417910 Cashiers(412010)
3398330 Cashiers(412011)
3297180 Protective Service Occupations(330000)
3217850 Financial Clerks(433000)
3150530 Building Cleaning and Pest Control Workers(372000)
3131390 Combined Food Preparation and Serving Workers Including Fast Food(353021)
3082890 Building Cleaning Workers(372010)
3077690 Cooks and Food Preparation Workers(352000)
2889970 Office Clerks General(439061)
2876000 Health Technologists and Technicians(292000)
2828110 Driver/Sales Workers and Truck Drivers(533030)
2729400 Other Installation Maintenance and Repair Occupations(499000)
2687310 Registered Nurses(291141)
2564560 Financial Specialists(132000)
2556920 Other Personal Care and Service Workers(399000)
2511130 Customer Service Representatives(434051)
2471030 Other Production Occupations(519000)
2445230 Waiters and Waitresses(353031)
2418020 Architecture and Engineering Occupations(170000)
2400490 Laborers and Freight Stock and Material Movers Hand(537062)
2352100 Nursing Psychiatric and Home Health Aides(311010)
2351130 Top Executives(111000)
2227470 Cooks(352010)
2207220 Secretaries and Administrative Assistants Except Legal Medical and Executive(436014)
2137730 Janitors and Cleaners Except Maids and Housekeeping Cleaners(372011)
2136840 Other Management Occupations(119000)
2049870 General and Operations Managers(111021)
1997640 Elementary and Middle School Teachers(252020)
1930750 Community and Social Service Occupations(210000)
1918310 Metal Workers and Plastic Workers(514000)
1878860 Stock Clerks and Order Fillers(435081)
1857280 Counselors Social Workers and Other Community and Social Service Specialists(211000)
1810560 Assemblers and Fabricators(512000)
1793700 Arts Design Entertainment Sports and Media Occupations(270000)
1736660 Sales Representatives Services(413000)
1730180 Sales Representatives Wholesale and Manufacturing(414010)
1625290 Heavy and Tractor-Trailer Truck Drivers(533032)
1624000 Operations Specialties Managers(113000)
1575060 Bookkeeping Accounting and Auditing Clerks(433031)
1574480 Engineers(172000)
1522210 Postsecondary Teachers(251000)
1507680 Vehicle and Mobile Equipment Mechanics Installers and Repairers(493000)
1492040 Software Developers and Programmers(151130)
1485490 Other Protective Service Workers(339000)
1453820 Other Education Training and Library Occupations(259000)
1448550 First-Line Supervisors of Sales Workers(411010)
1427740 Nursing Assistants(311014)
1421960 Other Healthcare Support Occupations(319000)
1404070 First-Line Supervisors of Office and Administrative Support Workers(431011)
1394640 Sales Representatives Wholesale and Manufacturing Except Technical and Scientific Products(414012)
1384290 Miscellaneous Assemblers and Fabricators(512090)
1353020 Elementary School Teachers Except Special Education(252021)
1334290 Miscellaneous Healthcare Support Occupations(319090)
1330930 Other Food Preparation and Serving Related Workers(359000)
1282920 Maintenance and Repair Workers General(499071)
1257000 Personal Care Aides(399021)
1216140 Law Enforcement Workers(333000)
1199770 First-Line Supervisors of Retail Sales Workers(411011)
1192590 Teacher Assistants(259041)
1187310 Accountants and Auditors(132011)
1160720 Other Teachers and Instructors(253000)
1144440 Life Physical and Social Science Occupations(190000)
1125160 Team Assemblers(512092)
1104790 Cooks Restaurant(352014)
1087550 Security Guards and Gaming Surveillance Officers(339030)
1077520 Security Guards(339032)
1052900 Legal Occupations(230000)
1041940 Secondary School Teachers(252030)
985470  Supervisors of Food Preparation and Serving Workers(351010)
981150  Receptionists and Information Clerks(434171)
960380  Secondary School Teachers Except Special and Career/Technical Education(252031)
950780  Grounds Maintenance Workers(373010)
934370  Business Operations Specialists All Other(131199)
929540  Maids and Housekeeping Cleaners(372012)
892360  Miscellaneous Teachers and Instructors(253090)
868770  Landscaping and Groundskeeping Workers(373011)
867340  First-Line Supervisors of Food Preparation and Serving Workers(351012)
852870  Construction Laborers(472061)
850220  Food Preparation Workers(352021)
834750  Miscellaneous Production Workers(519190)
826650  Sales Representatives Services All Other(413099)
799080  Home Health Aides(311011)
797010  Light Truck or Delivery Services Drivers(533033)
786200  Automotive Technicians and Repairers(493020)
767460  Food Processing Workers(513000)
738030  Computer Support Specialists(151150)
713730  Executive Secretaries and Executive Administrative Assistants(436011)
700820  Health Practitioner Support Technologists and Technicians(292050)
695610  Licensed Practical and Licensed Vocational Nurses(292061)
693170  Packers and Packagers Hand(537064)
686470  Software Developers Applications(151132)
684170  Other Sales and Related Workers(419000)
682950  Drafters Engineering Technicians and Mapping Technicians(173000)
668850  Counter and Rental Clerks and Parts Salespersons(412020)
663910  Lawyers Judges and Related Workers(231000)
661530  Shipping Receiving and Traffic Clerks(435071)
657500  Bus Drivers(533020)
642190  Police Officers(333050)
640230  Miscellaneous Community and Social Service Specialists(211090)
638810  Police and Sheriff's Patrol Officers(333051)
633480  Physicians and Surgeons(291060)
633390  Automotive Service Technicians and Mechanics(493023)
630620  Middle School Teachers Except Special and Career/Technical Education(252022)
629670  Advertising Marketing Promotions Public Relations and Sales Managers(112000)
622600  Substitute Teachers(253098)
617680  Database and Systems Administrators and Network Architects(151140)
617060  Carpenters(472031)
614970  Lawyers and Judicial Law Clerks(231010)
613750  Counselors(211010)
609870  Therapists(291120)
608500  Computer and Information Analysts(151120)
603310  Lawyers(231011)
603300  Social Workers(211020)
592830  First-Line Supervisors of Production and Operating Workers(511011)
587450  Management Analysts(131111)
584970  Medical Assistants(319092)
582970  Childcare Workers(399011)
579700  Bartenders(353011)
574440  Textile Apparel and Furnishings Workers(516000)
572780  Electrical and Electronic Equipment Mechanics Installers and Repairers(492000)
566930  Electricians(472111)
563540  Computer User Support Specialists(151151)
562110  Recreation and Fitness Workers(399030)
560350  Entertainment Attendants and Related Workers(393000)
556340  Media and Communication Workers(273000)
550820  Financial Analysts and Advisors(132050)
543410  Marketing and Sales Managers(112020)
536900  Human Resources Workers(131070)
531920  Art and Design Workers(271000)
528320  Computer Systems Analysts(151121)
521840  Industrial Truck and Tractor Operators(537051)
519910  Cooks Fast Food(352011)
518030  Financial Managers(113031)
516050  Medical Secretaries(436013)
514520  Tellers(433071)
510650  Preschool and Kindergarten Teachers(252010)
502280  Dishwashers(359021)
501000  Postal Service Workers(435050)
499440  Bus Drivers School or Special Client(533022)
496370  First-Line Supervisors of Construction Trades and Extraction Workers(471011)
494870  Special Education Teachers(252050)
493840  Personal Appearance Workers(395000)
491110  Entertainers and Performers Sports and Related Workers(272000)
490860  Billing and Posting Clerks(433021)
489750  Inspectors Testers Sorters Samplers and Weighers(519061)
476470  Counter Attendants Cafeteria Food Concession and Coffee Shop(353022)
468160  Market Research Analysts and Marketing Specialists(131161)
458990  Miscellaneous Postsecondary Teachers(251190)
456170  Human Resources Specialists(131071)
450730  Bailiffs Correctional Officers and Jailers(333010)
447130  Farming Fishing and Forestry Occupations(450000)
445630  Industrial Machinery Installation Repair and Maintenance Workers(499040)
445200  Designers(271020)
441950  Education Administrators(119030)
437610  Counter and Rental Clerks(412021)
434810  First-Line Supervisors of Mechanics Installers and Repairers(491011)
434420  Correctional Officers and Jailers(333012)
432950  Engineering Technicians Except Drafters(173020)
424960  Welding Soldering and Brazing Workers(514120)
420520  Helpers--Production Workers(519198)
413650  Pipelayers Plumbers Pipefitters and Steamfitters(472150)
410460  Dining Room and Cafeteria Attendants and Bartender Helpers(359011)
410230  Buyers and Purchasing Agents(131020)
405810  Driver/Sales Workers(533031)
402920  Construction Equipment Operators(472070)
402800  Cooks Institution and Cafeteria(352012)
392700  Machinists(514041)
388990  Legal Support Workers(232000)
384390  Other Construction and Related Workers(474000)
383570  Agricultural Workers(452000)
382400  Software Developers Systems Software(151133)
381760  Packaging and Filling Machine Operators and Tenders(519111)
374700  Insurance Sales Agents(413021)
374480  Supervisors of Transportation and Material Moving Workers(531000)
373440  Butchers and Other Meat Poultry and Fish Processing Workers(513020)
372670  Hosts and Hostesses Restaurant Lounge and Coffee Shop(359031)
372570  Plumbers Pipefitters and Steamfitters(472152)
369610  Welders Cutters Solderers and Brazers(514121)
368760  Pharmacy Technicians(292052)
365430  Network and Computer Systems Administrators(151142)
361900  Managers All Other(119199)
358920  Sales Managers(112022)
357690  Diagnostic Related Technologists and Technicians(292030)
357610  Miscellaneous Protective Service Workers(339090)
357280  Barbers Hairdressers Hairstylists and Cosmetologists(395010)
354800  Social and Human Service Assistants(211093)
352420  Preschool Teachers Except Special Education(252011)
351990  Life Physical and Social Science Technicians(194000)
349210  Miscellaneous Installation Maintenance and Repair Workers(499090)
346960  Bill and Account Collectors(433011)
344510  Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators(472073)
343140  Hairdressers Hairstylists and Cosmetologists(395012)
342520  Machine Tool Cutting Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514030)
335540  Sales Representatives Wholesale and Manufacturing Technical and Scientific Products(414011)
332560  Miscellaneous Agricultural Workers(452090)
331570  Other Transportation Workers(536000)
330360  Computer and Information Systems Managers(113021)
330180  Credit Counselors and Loan Officers(132070)
322170  Clinical Laboratory Technologists and Technicians(292010)
321790  Fire Fighting and Prevention Workers(332000)
321740  Cleaners of Vehicles and Equipment(537061)
321110  Recreation Workers(399032)
316340  Securities Commodities and Financial Services Sales Agents(413031)
315910  Miscellaneous Entertainment Attendants and Related Workers(393090)
315200  Plant and System Operators(518000)
314330  Dental Assistants(319091)
313880  Industrial Machinery Mechanics(499041)
311320  Physicians and Surgeons All Other(291069)
310320  Medical and Health Services Managers(119111)
308790  Firefighters(332011)
308530  Electrical and Electronics Engineers(172070)
307490  Postal Service Mail Carriers(435052)
302150  Computer Programmers(151131)
300580  Loan Officers(132072)
297050  Production Planning and Expediting Clerks(435061)
290780  Pharmacists(291051)
288430  Purchasing Agents Except Wholesale Retail and Farm Products(131023)
287240  Data Entry and Information Processing Workers(439020)
286710  Dispatchers(435030)
286520  Child Family and School Social Workers(211021)
281020  Arts Communications and Humanities Teachers Postsecondary(251120)
279980  Claims Adjusters Appraisers Examiners and Investigators(131030)
278790  Life Scientists(191000)
274510  Physical Scientists(192000)
274230  Amusement and Recreation Attendants(393091)
273750  Supervisors of Protective Service Workers(331000)
272580  Paralegals and Legal Assistants(232011)
270700  Mechanical Engineers(172141)
270150  First-Line Supervisors of Building and Grounds Cleaning and Maintenance Workers(371010)
269760  Teachers and Instructors All Other Except Substitute Teachers(253097)
269660  Extraction Workers(475000)
269650  Farmworkers and Laborers Crop Nursery and Greenhouse(452092)
269250  Electrical Electronics and Electromechanical Assemblers(512020)
268730  Administrative Services Managers(113011)
266280  Claims Adjusters Examiners and Investigators(131031)
263460  Civil Engineers(172051)
262610  Financial Analysts(132051)
261510  Industrial Engineers Including Health and Safety(172110)
261390  Heating Air Conditioning and Refrigeration Mechanics and Installers(499021)
254360  Printing Workers(515110)
253930  Librarians Curators and Archivists(254000)
252670  Insurance Claims and Policy Processing Clerks(439041)
250840  Food Servers Nonrestaurant(353041)
248770  First-Line Supervisors of Non-Retail Sales Workers(411012)
246970  Compliance Officers(131041)
246280  Educational Guidance School and Vocational Counselors(211012)
246240  Chief Executives(111011)
243080  Bus and Truck Mechanics and Diesel Engine Specialists(493031)
242350  Air Transportation Workers(532000)
241140  Hotel Motel and Resort Desk Clerks(434081)
241000  Fitness Trainers and Aerobics Instructors(399031)
240780  Athletes Coaches Umpires and Related Workers(272020)
239500  Training and Development Specialists(131151)
239140  Social Scientists and Related Workers(193000)
238720  Assemblers and Fabricators All Other(512099)
236990  Industrial Engineers(172112)
235760  Emergency Medical Technicians and Paramedics(292041)
234920  Miscellaneous Electrical and Electronic Equipment Mechanics Installers and Repairers(492090)
234520  Telemarketers(419041)
234180  Office and Administrative Support Workers All Other(439199)
231800  Education Administrators Elementary and Secondary School(119032)
231240  Parts Salespersons(412022)
229870  Woodworkers(517000)
228960  Line Installers and Repairers(499050)
227710  Construction Managers(119021)
226930  Radio and Telecommunications Equipment Installers and Repairers(492020)
224930  Health Teachers Postsecondary(251070)
224500  Helpers Construction Trades(473010)
220290  Miscellaneous Food Processing Workers(513090)
217500  Production Workers All Other(519199)
214330  Media and Communication Equipment Workers(274000)
213620  Telecommunications Equipment Installers and Repairers Except Line Installers(492022)
212910  Legal Secretaries(436012)
212510  Computer Occupations All Other(151199)
212440  Loan Interviewers and Clerks(434131)
211760  Coaches and Scouts(272022)
209130  Cost Estimators(131051)
208170  Painters and Paperhangers(472140)
208030  Public Relations Specialists(273031)
207330  Electrical and Electronic Equipment Assemblers(512022)
205950  Data Entry Keyers(439021)
204600  Painters Construction and Maintenance(472141)
202360  Self-Enrichment Education Teachers(253021)
200820  Special Education Teachers Kindergarten and Elementary School(252052)
200670  Physical Therapists(291123)
199330  Laundry and Dry-Cleaning Workers(516011)
199260  Drafters(173010)
198610  Food Service Managers(119051)
197540  Graphic Designers(271024)
197000  First-Line Supervisors of Transportation and Material-Moving Machine and Vehicle Operators(531031)
196520  Dental Hygienists(292021)
196490  Personal Financial Advisors(132052)
196380  Real Estate Brokers and Sales Agents(419020)
193400  Radiologic Technologists(292034)
193090  Supervisors of Personal Care and Service Workers(391000)
190710  Interviewers Except Eligibility and Loan(434111)
190390  Order Clerks(434151)
190330  Dispatchers Except Police Fire and Ambulance(435032)
190250  Cutting Punching and Press Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514031)
189490  Postsecondary Teachers All Other(251199)
189060  Writers and Editors(273040)
184740  Medical Records and Health Information Technicians(292071)
184490  Marketing Managers(112021)
181960  Crushing Grinding Polishing Mixing and Blending Workers(519020)
180800  Cooks Short Order(352015)
179320  Architectural and Engineering Managers(119041)
178260  Taxi Drivers and Chauffeurs(533041)
175530  Information and Record Clerks All Other(434199)
174690  Heavy Vehicle and Mobile Equipment Service Technicians and Mechanics(493040)
174550  Electrical Engineers(172071)
174490  Computer Network Support Specialists(151152)
173730  Bakers(513011)
172990  Animal Care and Service Workers(392000)
172990  Computer Control Programmers and Operators(514010)
171720  First-Line Supervisors of Helpers Laborers and Material Movers Hand(531021)
171140  Property Real Estate and Community Association Managers(119141)
168960  First-Line Supervisors of Housekeeping and Janitorial Workers(371011)
168090  Health Specialties Teachers Postsecondary(251071)
167200  Industrial Production Managers(113051)
166750  Printing Press Operators(515112)
166440  Occupational Therapy and Physical Therapist Assistants and Aides(312000)
166400  Payroll and Timekeeping Clerks(433051)
161990  First-Line Supervisors of Personal Service Workers(391021)
161820  Nonfarm Animal Caretakers(392021)
161710  Medical and Clinical Laboratory Technologists(292011)
160590  Architects Surveyors and Cartographers(171000)
160460  Medical and Clinical Laboratory Technicians(292012)
158240  Kindergarten Teachers Except Special Education(252012)
158050  Bus Drivers Transit and Intercity(533021)
157660  Real Estate Sales Agents(419022)
156830  Painting Workers(519120)
156510  Actors Producers and Directors(272010)
155820  Cement Masons Concrete Finishers and Terrazzo Workers(472050)
154220  Advertising Sales Agents(413011)
152570  Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers(472051)
150310  Meat Poultry and Fish Cutters and Trimmers(513022)
148280  File Clerks(434071)
148040  Computer-Controlled Machine Tool Operators Metal and Plastic(514011)
146560  First-Line Supervisors of Law Enforcement Workers(331010)
145920  Healthcare Social Workers(211022)
144780  Miscellaneous Life Physical and Social Science Technicians(194090)
144540  Other Healthcare Practitioners and Technical Occupations(299000)
142070  Sewing Machine Operators(516031)
141200  Mathematical Science Occupations(152000)
140650  Highway Maintenance Workers(474051)
140410  Molders and Molding Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514070)
140080  Computer Network Architects(151143)
138460  Installation Maintenance and Repair Workers All Other(499099)
138260  Reservation and Transportation Ticket Agents and Travel Clerks(434181)
137460  Financial Specialists All Other(132099)
137140  Automotive Body and Related Repairers(493021)
137050  Butchers and Meat Cutters(513021)
137040  Electrical and Electronics Engineering Technicians(173023)
136550  Miscellaneous Personal Appearance Workers(395090)
136440  Parking Lot Attendants(536021)
135520  Special Education Teachers Secondary School(252054)
135270  Human Resources Assistants Except Payroll and Timekeeping(434161)
135070  Lifeguards Ski Patrol and Other Recreational Protective Service Workers(339092)
133990  Electronics Engineers Except Computer(172072)
133780  Instructional Coordinators(259031)
133150  Librarians(254021)
132530  Sheet Metal Workers(472211)
132230  Tax Examiners Collectors and Preparers and Revenue Agents(132080)
131070  Education Administrators Postsecondary(119033)
129310  Environmental Scientists and Geoscientists(192040)
128540  Molding Coremaking and Casting Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514072)
128490  Court Municipal and License Clerks(434031)
127240  Forming Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514020)
126980  Helpers--Installation Maintenance and Repair Workers(499098)
126500  Speech-Language Pathologists(291127)
126030  Graduate Teaching Assistants(251191)
125670  Logisticians(131081)
125640  Physical Therapist Assistants and Aides(312020)
124810  Family and General Practitioners(291062)
124570  Engineers All Other(172199)
124440  Gaming Services Workers(393010)
122870  Rail Transportation Workers(534000)
122670  Mixing and Blending Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519023)
122400  Eligibility Interviewers Government Programs(434061)
122050  Nurse Practitioners(291171)
122030  Miscellaneous Vehicle and Mobile Equipment Mechanics Installers and Repairers(493090)
121590  Postal Service Mail Sorters Processors and Processing Machine Operators(435053)
121470  Communications Equipment Operators(432000)
121200  Vocational Education Teachers Postsecondary(251194)
121020  Web Developers(151134)
120850  Food Batchmakers(513092)
120010  Mental Health Counselors(211014)
119410  Respiratory Therapists(291126)
119280  Mobile Heavy Equipment Mechanics Except Engines(493042)
118130  Chefs and Head Cooks(351011)
117820  Psychologists(193030)
117120  Woodworking Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(517040)
116830  Aircraft Mechanics and Service Technicians(493011)
116670  Social and Community Service Managers(119151)
116610  Human Resources Managers(113121)
116410  Miscellaneous Legal Support Workers(232090)
116310  Social Sciences Teachers Postsecondary(251060)
115390  Dentists(291020)
115170  Refuse and Recyclable Material Collectors(537081)
114540  Electrical Power-Line Installers and Repairers(499051)
114420  Telecommunications Line Installers and Repairers(499052)
113920  Aircraft Pilots and Flight Engineers(532010)
113700  Ushers Lobby Attendants and Ticket Takers(393031)
113020  Protective Service Workers All Other(339099)
112170  Database Administrators(151141)
111950  Phlebotomists(319097)
111640  Water and Wastewater Treatment Plant and System Operators(518031)
110940  Computer Automated Teller and Office Machine Repairers(492011)
110560  Wholesale and Retail Buyers Except Farm Products(131022)
110520  Occupational Therapists(291122)
109600  Education Training and Library Workers All Other(259099)
109580  Miscellaneous Health Technologists and Technicians(292090)
109460  Mental Health and Substance Abuse Social Workers(211023)
109320  Derrick Rotary Drill and Service Unit Operators Oil Gas and Mining(475010)
108890  Switchboard Operators Including Answering Service(432011)
108720  Detectives and Criminal Investigators(333021)
108030  Chemical Processing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519010)
107130  Miscellaneous Plant and System Operators(518090)
107000  Architects Except Naval(171010)
106160  Medical Scientists(191040)
106000  Transportation Storage and Distribution Managers(113071)
104750  Automotive and Watercraft Service Attendants(536031)
104730  Clinical Counseling and School Psychologists(193031)
104340  Machine Feeders and Offbearers(537063)
103890  Rehabilitation Counselors(211015)
103650  Roofers(472181)
103210  Biological Scientists(191020)
102920  Miscellaneous Metal Workers and Plastic Workers(514190)
101850  Drywall Installers Ceiling Tile Installers and Tapers(472080)
101660  Broadcast and Sound Engineering Technicians and Radio Operators(274010)
101420  First-Line Supervisors of Police and Detectives(331012)
101190  First-Line Supervisors of Landscaping Lawn Service and Groundskeeping Workers(371012)
100800  Library Assistants Clerical(434121)
100740  Medical Scientists Except Epidemiologists(191042)
100510  Tire Repairers and Changers(493093)
99190   Mail Clerks and Mail Machine Operators Except Postal Service(439051)
98980   Healthcare Support Workers All Other(319099)
98510   Flight Attendants(532031)
98450   Surgical Technologists(292055)
98160   Multiple Machine Tool Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514081)
97990   Dentists General(291021)
97500   Art Drama and Music Teachers Postsecondary(251121)
97350   Editors(273041)
97300   Producers and Directors(272012)
96440   Miscellaneous Sales and Related Workers(419090)
96390   Police Fire and Ambulance Dispatchers(435031)
96170   Health Technologists and Technicians All Other(292099)
96060   Gaming Dealers(393011)
95750   Residential Advisors(399041)
94820   Special Education Teachers Middle School(252053)
94260   Library Technicians(254031)
93710   Community and Social Service Specialists All Other(211099)
93300   Veterinary Technologists and Technicians(292056)
93000   Merchandise Displayers and Window Trimmers(271026)
92870   Chemists and Materials Scientists(192030)
92170   Paper Goods Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519196)
91720   Insurance Underwriters(132053)
91670   Physician Assistants(291071)
91520   Architectural and Civil Drafters(173011)
90730   Maintenance Workers Machinery(499043)
90590   Coating Painting and Spraying Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519121)
89420   Math and Computer Teachers Postsecondary(251020)
88900   Architects Except Landscape and Naval(171011)
88830   Sales and Related Workers All Other(419099)
88740   Environmental Scientists and Specialists Including Health(192041)
88740   Models Demonstrators and Product Promoters(419010)
88410   Construction and Building Inspectors(474011)
88170   Cabinetmakers and Bench Carpenters(517011)
87670   Massage Therapists(319011)
86950   Operations Research Analysts(152031)
86810   Probation Officers and Correctional Treatment Specialists(211092)
86710   Artists and Related Workers(271010)
86070   Slaughterers and Meat Packers(513023)
85970   Chemists(192031)
85180   Substance Abuse and Behavioral Disorder Counselors(211011)
85030   Business Teachers Postsecondary(251011)
85020   Drywall and Ceiling Tile Installers(472081)
83600   Demonstrators and Product Promoters(419011)
81560   Career/Technical Education Teachers Secondary School(252032)
81300   Word Processors and Typists(439022)
80970   Compensation Benefits and Job Analysis Specialists(131141)
80180   Information Security Analysts(151122)
79780   Labor Relations Specialists(131075)
79120   Occupational Health and Safety Specialists and Technicians(299010)
79090   Manicurists and Pedicurists(395092)
78090   Cutting Workers(519030)
78050   Structural Metal Fabricators and Fitters(512041)
77940   Meeting Convention and Event Planners(131121)
77480   Cargo and Freight Agents(435011)
76910   Physical Therapist Assistants(312021)
76360   Computer Hardware Engineers(172061)
76320   English Language and Literature Teachers Postsecondary(251123)
76220   Medical Dental and Ophthalmic Laboratory Technicians(519080)
75950   Tool and Die Makers(514111)
75760   Airline Pilots Copilots and Flight Engineers(532011)
75220   Baggage Porters Bellhops and Concierges(396010)
74990   Miscellaneous Media and Communication Workers(273090)
74390   Textile Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(516060)
73470   Religious Workers(212000)
73450   Roustabouts Oil and Gas(475071)
73110   Opticians Dispensing(292081)
72860   Psychiatric Aides(311013)
72640   Biological Technicians(194021)
72520   Extruding and Drawing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514021)

Footnotes:  
(1) Estimates for detailed occupations do not sum to the totals because the totals include occupations not shown separately. Estimates do not include self-employed workers.    
SOC code: Standard Occupational Classification code -- see http://www.bls.gov/soc/home.htm  

Data extracted on May 11 2015
```

Answer (score 2):

The table from my [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/17046/7646), continued.

```
72450   Water Transportation Workers(535000)
71980   Carpet Floor and Tile Installers and Finishers(472040)
71910   Postal Service Clerks(435051)
71760   Couriers and Messengers(435021)
71300   Civil Engineering Technicians(173022)
71090   Miscellaneous Textile Apparel and Furnishings Workers(516090)
71060   Veterinary Assistants and Laboratory Animal Caretakers(319096)
70840   Purchasing Managers(113061)
70810   Woodworking Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Except Sawing(517042)
70580   Brickmasons Blockmasons and Stonemasons(472020)
70190   Procurement Clerks(433061)
70130   Grinding/Lapping/Polishing/Buffing Machine Tool Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Pla(514033)
69430   Weighers Measurers Checkers and Samplers Recordkeeping(435111)
69390   Credit Analysts(132041)
69080   Aerospace Engineers(172011)
68590   Tax Preparers(132082)
68280   Helpers--Electricians(473013)
68080   Sales Engineers(419031)
67640   Engineering Technicians Except Drafters All Other(173029)
67640   Pest Control Workers(372021)
67490   Extruding Forming Pressing and Compacting Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519041)
67310   First-Line Supervisors of Protective Service Workers All Other(331099)
67140   Life Physical and Social Science Technicians All Other(194099)
66530   Office Machine Operators Except Computer(439071)
66310   Crossing Guards(339091)
65990   Adult Basic and Secondary Education and Literacy Teachers and Instructors(253011)
65900   Electrical and Electronics Repairers Commercial and Industrial Equipment(492094)
65810   Precision Instrument and Equipment Repairers(499060)
65680   Industrial Engineering Technicians(173026)
65420   Miscellaneous Health Practitioners and Technical Workers(299090)
65130   Occupational Health and Safety Specialists(299011)
64860   Small Engine Mechanics(493050)
64750   Travel Agents(413041)
64710   Chemical Equipment Operators and Tenders(519011)
64540   Psychiatric Technicians(292053)
64510   Education and Library Science Teachers Postsecondary(251080)
64490   Life Sciences Teachers Postsecondary(251040)
64070   Mechanical Drafters(173013)
63770   Funeral Service Workers(394000)
63760   Chemical Technicians(194031)
63640   Tax Examiners and Collectors and Revenue Agents(132081)
63220   Appraisers and Assessors of Real Estate(132021)
62570   Cutting and Slicing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519032)
62470   Veterinarians(291131)
62080   Service Unit Operators Oil Gas and Mining(475013)
61410   Social Workers All Other(211029)
61210   Medical Transcriptionists(319094)
60770   Musicians Singers and Related Workers(272040)
60200   Audio and Video Equipment Technicians(274011)
60160   Security and Fire Alarm Systems Installers(492098)
60010   Structural Iron and Steel Workers(472221)
59980   Education Teachers Postsecondary(251081)
59870   First-Line Supervisors of Fire Fighting and Prevention Workers(331021)
59760   Diagnostic Medical Sonographers(292032)
59490   Dietitians and Nutritionists(291031)
59340   Brickmasons and Blockmasons(472021)
59210   Actors(272011)
59090   Personal Care and Service Workers All Other(399099)
58880   Power Plant Operators Distributors and Dispatchers(518010)
58510   Control and Valve Installers and Repairers(499010)
58210   Motor Vehicle Operators All Other(533099)
58060   Computer Operators(439011)
57240   Brokerage Clerks(434011)
57120   Budget Analysts(132031)
57020   Health Educators(211091)
56920   Public Relations and Fundraising Managers(112031)
56840   Nursing Instructors and Teachers Postsecondary(251072)
55360   Welding Soldering and Brazing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(514122)
55230   Fundraisers(131131)
55020   Legislators(111031)
54940   Paving Surfacing and Tamping Equipment Operators(472071)
54010   Mathematical Science Teachers Postsecondary(251022)
53590   Dredge Excavating and Loading Machine Operators(537030)
53580   Surveyors Cartographers and Photogrammetrists(171020)
53290   Natural Sciences Managers(119121)
53240   Environmental Engineers(172081)
52960   Title Examiners Abstractors and Searchers(232093)
52850   Insulation Workers(472130)
52750   Biological Science Teachers Postsecondary(251042)
52420   Orderlies(311015)
52260   New Accounts Clerks(434141)
52250   Photographers(274021)
51820   Physical Sciences Teachers Postsecondary(251050)
51430   Print Binding and Finishing Workers(515113)
51350   Helpers--Pipelayers Plumbers Pipefitters and Steamfitters(473015)
51080   Cardiovascular Technologists and Technicians(292031)
50750   Surveying and Mapping Technicians(173031)
50550   Medical Equipment Preparers(319093)
50150   Pressers Textile Garment and Related Materials(516021)
49950   Painters Transportation Equipment(519122)
49460   Interpreters and Translators(273091)
49170   Miscellaneous Social Scientists and Related Workers(193090)
48940   Judges Magistrates and Other Judicial Workers(231020)
48730   Physical Therapist Aides(312022)
48390   Internists General(291063)
48210   Technical Writers(273042)
47880   Community Health Workers(211094)
47560   Mechanical Engineering Technicians(173027)
47470   Excavating and Loading Machine and Dragline Operators(537032)
47150   Education Administrators Preschool and Childcare Center/Program(119031)
46990   Electromechanical Equipment Assemblers(512023)
46590   News Analysts Reporters and Correspondents(273020)
46510   Clergy(212011)
46320   Credit Authorizers Checkers and Clerks(434041)
46320   Sawing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Wood(517041)
45520   Food Preparation and Serving Related Workers All Other(359099)
45150   First-Line Supervisors of Correctional Officers(331011)
45120   Legal Support Workers All Other(232099)
45050   Floral Designers(271023)
45010   Interior Designers(271025)
44540   Crane and Tower Operators(537021)
44470   Forest Conservation and Logging Workers(454000)
44170   Baggage Porters and Bellhops(396011)
43970   Locomotive Engineers and Operators(534010)
43840   Engineering and Architecture Teachers Postsecondary(251030)
43690   Food Processing Workers All Other(513099)
43500   Writers and Authors(273043)
43310   Separating Filtering Clarifying Precipitating and Still Machine Setters Operators and Te(519012)
43220   Transportation Security Screeners(339093)
42900   Railroad Conductors and Yardmasters(534031)
42820   Glaziers(472121)
42770   Television Video and Motion Picture Camera Operators and Editors(274030)
42570   Lathe and Turning Machine Tool Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514034)
42280   Reporters and Correspondents(273022)
42250   Hazardous Materials Removal Workers(474041)
41970   Surveyors(171022)
41850   Law Criminal Justice and Social Work Teachers Postsecondary(251110)
41700   Petroleum Pump System Operators Refinery Operators and Gaugers(518093)
41430   Medical Equipment Repairers(499062)
41290   Control and Valve Installers and Repairers Except Mechanical Door(499012)
41240   Pharmacy Aides(319095)
41080   Pipelayers(472151)
41070   Surgeons(291067)
40840   Healthcare Practitioners and Technical Workers All Other(299099)
40800   Occupational Therapy Assistants and Aides(312010)
40630   Aircraft Structure Surfaces Rigging and Systems Assemblers(512011)
40300   Power Plant Operators(518013)
39890   Transportation Workers All Other(536099)
39640   Tree Trimmers and Pruners(373013)
39620   Special Education Teachers All Other(252059)
39290   Millwrights(499044)
38900   Musicians and Singers(272042)
38900   Helpers--Carpenters(473012)
38830   Conveyor Operators and Tenders(537011)
38720   Real Estate Brokers(419021)
38470   Locomotive Engineers(534011)
38330   Engine and Other Machine Assemblers(512031)
38290   Skincare Specialists(395094)
38190   Tour and Travel Guides(397010)
38170   Commercial Pilots(532012)
37930   Psychology Teachers Postsecondary(251066)
37680   Announcers(273010)
37600   Logging Workers(454020)
37550   Stationary Engineers and Boiler Operators(518021)
37510   Financial Clerks All Other(433099)
37490   Chemical Plant and System Operators(518091)
36850   Food Cooking Machine Operators and Tenders(513093)
36830   Financial Examiners(132061)
36650   Engineering Teachers Postsecondary(251032)
36590   Nurse Anesthetists(291151)
36470   Ophthalmic Medical Technicians(292057)
36210   Meter Readers Utilities(435041)
36180   Prepress Technicians and Workers(515111)
36100   Graders and Sorters Agricultural Products(452041)
35900   Plating and Coating Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514193)
35820   Urban and Regional Planners(193051)
35410   Computer Science Teachers Postsecondary(251021)
35320   Farm Equipment Mechanics and Service Technicians(493041)
35320   Dental Laboratory Technicians(519081)
35310   Health Diagnosing and Treating Practitioners All Other(291199)
35100   Tour Guides and Escorts(397011)
34950   Funeral Attendants(394021)
34760   Ship and Boat Captains and Operators(535020)
34610   Molders Shapers and Casters Except Metal and Plastic(519195)
34000   Geoscientists Except Hydrologists and Geographers(192042)
33760   Environmental Science and Protection Technicians Including Health(194091)
33740   Petroleum Engineers(172171)
33470   Chemical Engineers(172041)
33370   Rolling Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514023)
33340   Optometrists(291041)
33270   Home Appliance Repairers(499031)
33140   Art Directors(271011)
33130   Magnetic Resonance Imaging Technologists(292035)
32320   Miscellaneous Construction and Related Workers(474090)
32230   Biological Scientists All Other(191029)
32230   Occupational Therapy Assistants(312011)
32010   Social Scientists and Related Workers All Other(193099)
31920   Education Administrators All Other(119039)
31740   Lodging Managers(119081)
31670   Agricultural and Food Scientists(191010)
31590   Tile and Marble Setters(472044)
31540   Farmworkers Farm Ranch and Aquacultural Animals(452093)
31350   Biochemists and Biophysicists(191021)
31190   Construction and Related Workers All Other(474099)
31100   First-Line Supervisors of Gaming Workers(391010)
31050   Concierges(396012)
31010   Pediatricians General(291065)
30880   Foreign Language and Literature Teachers Postsecondary(251124)
30840   Coin Vending and Amusement Machine Servicers and Repairers(499091)
30690   Captains Mates and Pilots of Water Vessels(535021)
30540   Metal Furnace Operators Tenders Pourers and Casters(514050)
30310   Forest and Conservation Technicians(194093)
30220   Radio and Television Announcers(273011)
30150   Marriage and Family Therapists(211013)
30060   Anesthesiologists(291061)
29980   Crushing Grinding and Polishing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(519021)
29920   Air Traffic Controllers and Airfield Operations Specialists(532020)
29870   Training and Development Managers(113131)
29830   Chiropractors(291011)
29770   Upholsterers(516093)
29600   Credit Counselors(132071)
29590   Pumping Station Operators(537070)
29470   Communications Teachers Postsecondary(251122)
29410   Commercial and Industrial Designers(271021)
29390   Electrical and Electronics Drafters(173012)
29340   Advertising and Promotions Managers(112011)
29320   Grinding and Polishing Workers Hand(519022)
29220   Outdoor Power Equipment and Other Small Engine Mechanics(493053)
29000   Multimedia Artists and Animators(271014)
28800   Photographic Process Workers and Processing Machine Operators(519151)
28690   Dietetic Technicians(292051)
28660   Insulation Workers Mechanical(472132)
28350   Conservation Scientists and Foresters(191030)
28240   Counselors All Other(211019)
28090   Judges Magistrate Judges and Magistrates(231023)
27780   Social Science Research Assistants(194061)
27640   Sailors and Marine Oilers(535011)
27610   Ophthalmic Laboratory Technicians(519083)
26970   Statisticians(152041)
26880   Private Detectives and Investigators(339021)
26600   Broadcast Technicians(274012)
26590   Electronic Home Entertainment Equipment Installers and Repairers(492097)
26510   Archivists Curators and Museum Technicians(254010)
26480   Rotary Drill Operators Oil and Gas(475012)
26160   Tailors Dressmakers and Sewers(516050)
26100   Agricultural Equipment Operators(452091)
26050   Carpet Installers(472041)
26010   Logging Equipment Operators(454022)
25740   Textile Winding Twisting and Drawing Out Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(516064)
25530   Media and Communication Workers All Other(273099)
25160   Morticians Undertakers and Funeral Directors(394031)
25080   Psychiatrists(291066)
24990   Materials Engineers(172131)
24960   Computer Numerically Controlled Machine Tool Programmers Metal and Plastic(514012)
24530   Health and Safety Engineers Except Mining Safety Engineers and Inspectors(172111)
24460   Film and Video Editors(274032)
24350   Septic Tank Servicers and Sewer Pipe Cleaners(474071)
24350   Transportation Inspectors(536051)
24210   Computer and Information Research Scientists(151111)
24180   Insulation Workers Floor Ceiling and Wall(472131)
24130   Helpers--Extraction Workers(475081)
24100   Gaming Supervisors(391011)
24080   Special Education Teachers Preschool(252051)
23790   Pesticide Handlers Sprayers and Applicators Vegetation(373012)
23640   History Teachers Postsecondary(251125)
23580   Semiconductor Processors(519141)
23570   Helpers--Brickmasons Blockmasons Stonemasons and Tile and Marble Setters(473011)
23210   Philosophy and Religion Teachers Postsecondary(251126)
23200   Jewelers and Precious Stone and Metal Workers(519071)
23030   Physical Scientists All Other(192099)
22910   Material Moving Workers All Other(537199)
22860   Air Traffic Controllers(532021)
22760   Textile Knitting and Weaving Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(516063)
22400   Athletic Trainers(299091)
22120   Electrical and Electronics Repairers Powerhouse Substation and Relay(492095)
22110   Milling and Planing Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514035)
22100   Metal Workers and Plastic Workers All Other(514199)
21880   Music Directors and Composers(272041)
21740   Obstetricians and Gynecologists(291064)
21490   Actuaries(152011)
21470   Chemistry Teachers Postsecondary(251052)
21340   Forging Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514022)
21060   Railroad Brake Signal and Switch Operators(534021)
20990   Fence Erectors(474031)
20980   Heat Treating Equipment Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514191)
20960   Mining Machine Operators(475040)
20850   Metal-Refining Furnace Operators and Tenders(514051)
20760   Plasterers and Stucco Masons(472161)
20760   Derrick Operators Oil and Gas(475011)
20670   Microbiologists(191022)
20640   Agricultural and Food Science Technicians(194011)
20590   Elevator Installers and Repairers(474021)
20590   Furnace Kiln Oven Drier and Kettle Operators and Tenders(519051)
20350   Riggers(499096)
20320   Nuclear Medicine Technologists(292033)
20210   Motorboat Mechanics and Service Technicians(493051)
20200   Tailors Dressmakers and Custom Sewers(516052)
20080   Biomedical Engineers(172031)
20080   Rail Car Repairers(493043)
19770   Extruding and Forming Machine Setters Operators and Tenders Synthetic and Glass Fibers(516091)
19580   Gaming Change Persons and Booth Cashiers(412012)
19350   Ambulance Drivers and Attendants Except Emergency Medical Technicians(533011)
19210   Conservation Scientists(191031)
19190   Helpers Construction Trades All Other(473019)
19160   Earth Drillers Except Oil and Gas(475021)
18970   Zoologists and Wildlife Biologists(191023)
18890   Food and Tobacco Roasting Baking and Drying Machine Operators and Tenders(513091)
18850   Directors Religious Activities and Education(212021)
18770   Fiberglass Laminators and Fabricators(512091)
18680   Economists(193011)
18650   Recreation and Fitness Studies Teachers Postsecondary(251193)
18600   Cooks All Other(352019)
18570   Grounds Maintenance Workers All Other(373019)
18530   First-Line Supervisors of Farming Fishing and Forestry Workers(451011)
18530   Reinforcing Iron and Rebar Workers(472171)
18450   Astronomers and Physicists(192010)
18330   Court Reporters(232091)
18310   Camera Operators Television Video and Motion Picture(274031)
18210   Adhesive Bonding Machine Operators and Tenders(519191)
18110   Landscape Architects(171012)
18080   Environmental Engineering Technicians(173025)
17950   Recreational Therapists(291125)
17930   Postmasters and Mail Superintendents(119131)
17840   Fashion Designers(271022)
17830   Locker Room Coatroom and Dressing Room Attendants(393093)
17680   Tire Builders(519197)
17650   Media and Communication Equipment Workers All Other(274099)
17580   Entertainment Attendants and Related Workers All Other(393099)
17510   Umpires Referees and Other Sports Officials(272023)
17470   Drilling and Boring Machine Tool Setters Operators and Tenders Metal and Plastic(514032)
17380   Electric Motor Power Tool and Related Repairers(492092)
17360   Cleaning Washing and Metal Pickling Equipment Operators and Tenders(519192)
17270   Dancers and Choreographers(272030)
17220   Mechanical Door Repairers(499011)
17210   Boilermakers(472011)
17150   Avionics Technicians(492091)
17090   Locksmiths and Safe Repairers(499094)
17050   Political Science Teachers Postsecondary(251065)
16900   Sociology Teachers Postsecondary(251067)
16820   Tapers(472082)
16790   Physicists(192012)
16560   Shampooers(395093)
16520   Nuclear Engineers(172161)
16380   Compensation and Benefits Managers(113111)
16380   Radiation Therapists(291124)
16380   Transportation Attendants Except Flight Attendants(536061)
16350   Gaming Cage Workers(433041)
16320   Gas Plant Operators(518092)
16310   Bailiffs(333011)
16280   Painting Coating and Decorating Workers(519123)
16220   Gaming Service Workers All Other(393019)
16110   Textile Apparel and Furnishings Workers All Other(516099)
16020   Geological and Petroleum Technicians(194041)
15990   Law Teachers Postsecondary(251112)
15780   Entertainers and Performers Sports and Related Workers All Other(272099)
15670   Automotive Glass Installers and Repairers(493022)
15620   Building Cleaning Workers All Other(372019)
15520   Cutters and Trimmers Hand(519031)
15420   Motorcycle Mechanics(493052)
15410   Survey Researchers(193022)
15320   Furniture Finishers(517021)
15150   Soil and Plant Scientists(191013)
14930   Coil Winders Tapers and Finishers(512021)
14890   Criminal Justice and Law Enforcement Teachers Postsecondary(251111)
14820   Rail-Track Laying and Maintenance Equipment Operators(474061)
14430   Electro-Mechanical Technicians(173024)
14370   Textile Cutting Machine Setters Operators and Tenders(516062)
14270   Drafters All Other(173019)
14170   Food Scientists and Technologists(191012)
14160   Physics Teachers Postsecondary(251054)
14160   Electrical and Electronics Installers and Repairers Transportation Equipment(492093)
14140   Administrative Law Judges Adjudicators and Hearing Officers(231021)
14140   Barbers(395011)
14110   Statistical Assistants(439111)
14000   Career/Technical Education Teachers Middle School(252023)
13990   Occupational Health and Safety Technicians(299012)
13800   Agricultural Inspectors(452011)
13750   Sound Engineering Technicians(274014)
13710   Economics Teachers Postsecondary(251063)
13690   Insurance Appraisers Auto Damage(131032)
13570   Forensic Science Technicians(194092)
13450   Animal Control Workers(339011)
13310   Desktop Publishers(439031)
13310   Radio Cellular and Tower Equipment Installers and Repairers(492021)
13290   Medical Appliance Technicians(519082)
13070   Layout Workers Metal and Plastic(514192)
13000   Fire Inspectors(332020)
12720   Wellhead Pumpers(537073)
12490   Tank Car Truck and Ship Loaders(537121)
12250   Audiologists(291181)
12170   Pump Operators Except Wellhead Pumpers(537072)
12160   Gaming and Sports Book Writers and Runners(393012)
12100   Fine Artists Including Painters Sculptors and Illustrators(271013)
11980   Psychologists All Other(193039)
11870   Foundry Mold and Coremakers(514071)
11860   Agents and Business Managers of Artists Performers and Athletes(131011)
11770   Therapists All Other(291129)
11660   Judicial Law Clerks(231012)
11640   Helpers--Roofers(473016)
11610   Cartographers and Photogrammetrists(171021)
11610   Plant and System Operators All Other(518099)
11570   Helpers--Painters Paperhangers Plasterers and Stucco Masons(473014)
11540   Continuous Mining Machine Operators(475041)
11520   Athletes and Sports Competitors(272021)
11510   Textile Bleaching and Dyeing Machine Operators and Tenders(516061)
11460   Electronic Equipment Installers and Repairers Motor Vehicles(492096)
11370   Fire Inspectors and Investigators(332021)
11300   Subway and Streetcar Operators(534041)
11260   Shoe and Leather Workers(516040)
11250   Buyers and Purchasing Agents Farm Products(131021)
11250   Stonemasons(472022)
11240   Dancers(272031)
11230   Aerospace Engineering and Operations Technicians(173021)
11200   Curators(254012)
11180   Precision Instrument and Equipment Repairers All Other(499069)
11180   Power Distributors and Dispatchers(518012)
11170   Animal Trainers(392011)
11030   Social Sciences Teachers Postsecondary All Other(251069)
10990   Recreational Vehicle Service Technicians(493092)
10970   Social Work Teachers Postsecondary(251113)
10890   Atmospheric Earth Marine and Space Sciences Teachers Postsecondary(251051)
10860   Tool Grinders Filers and Sharpeners(514194)
10850   Atmospheric and Space Scientists(192021)
10610   Respiratory Therapy Technicians(292054)
10520   Bicycle Repairers(493091)
10500   Proofreaders and Copy Markers(439081)
10460   Set and Exhibit Designers(271027)
10220   Telephone Operators(432021)
10060   Ship Engineers(535031)
10030   Gaming Surveillance Officers and Gaming Investigators(339031)
9950    Museum Technicians and Conservators(254013)
9910    Model Makers and Patternmakers Metal and Plastic(514060)
9890    Agricultural Sciences Teachers Postsecondary(251041)
9830    Floor Layers Except Carpet Wood and Hard Tiles(472042)
9770    Emergency Management Directors(119161)
9690    Pourers and Casters Metal(514052)
9400    Life Scientists All Other(191099)
9150    Area Ethnic and Cultural Studies Teachers Postsecondary(251062)
9140    Foresters(191032)
8960    Audio-Visual and Multimedia Collections Specialists(259011)
8910    Podiatrists(291081)
8900    Farm and Home Management Advisors(259021)
8680    Parking Enforcement Workers(333041)
8630    Etchers and Engravers(519194)
8570    Occupational Therapy Aides(312012)
8330    Funeral Service Managers(119061)
8200    Mining and Geological Engineers Including Mining Safety Engineers(172151)
8110    Religious Workers All Other(212099)
8070    Cooling and Freezing Equipment Operators and Tenders(519193)
7970    Explosives Workers Ordnance Handling Experts and Blasters(475031)
7880    Signal and Track Switch Repairers(499097)
7830    Orthotists and Prosthetists(292091)
7710    Shoe and Leather Workers and Repairers(516041)
7700    Artists and Related Workers All Other(271019)
7660    Musical Instrument Repairers and Tuners(499063)
7610    Door-to-Door Sales Workers News and Street Vendors and Related Workers(419091)
7580    Correspondence Clerks(434021)
7570    Marine Engineers and Naval Architects(172121)
7450    Public Address System and Other Announcers(273012)
7400    Nuclear Power Reactor Operators(518011)
7190    Architecture Teachers Postsecondary(251031)
7050    Airfield Operations Specialists(532022)
7040    Anthropologists and Archeologists(193091)
7000    Slot Supervisors(391012)
6960    Mine Cutting and Channeling Machine Operators(475042)
6940    Woodworkers All Other(517099)
6900    Materials Scientists(192032)
6890    Designers All Other(271029)
6870    Forest and Conservation Workers(454011)
6710    Arbitrators Mediators and Conciliators(231022)
6660    Exercise Physiologists(291128)
6580    Hydrologists(192043)
6490    Traffic Technicians(536041)
6380    Nuclear Technicians(194051)
6290    Motion Picture Projectionists(393021)
6270    Costume Attendants(393092)
6190    Orthodontists(291023)
6140    Model Makers Metal and Plastic(514061)
6100    Anthropology and Archeology Teachers Postsecondary(251061)
6090    Fallers(454021)
6030    Choreographers(272032)
5960    Sewers Hand(516051)
5820    Fish and Game Wardens(333031)
5750    Aircraft Cargo Handling Supervisors(531011)
5710    Roof Bolters Mining(475061)
5640    Political Scientists(193094)
5570    Hearing Aid Specialists(292092)
5450    Dentists All Other Specialists(291029)
5440    Fabric and Apparel Patternmakers(516092)
5420    Epidemiologists(191041)
5360    Archivists(254011)
5320    Extraction Workers All Other(475099)
5300    Environmental Science Teachers Postsecondary(251053)
5270    Agricultural Workers All Other(452099)
5170    Solar Photovoltaic Installers(472231)
5140    Models(419012)
5120    Oral and Maxillofacial Surgeons(291022)
5110    Nurse Midwives(291161)
4760    Craft Artists(271012)
4700    Gas Compressor and Gas Pumping Station Operators(537071)
4540    Library Science Teachers Postsecondary(251082)
4510    Floor Sanders and Finishers(472043)
4440    Geography Teachers Postsecondary(251064)
4310    Broadcast News Analysts(273021)
4300    Farmers Ranchers and Other Agricultural Managers(119013)
4220    Loading Machine Operators Underground Mining(537033)
4060    Motorboat Operators(535022)
3900    Rail Yard Engineers Dinkey Operators and Hostlers(534013)
3870    Gaming Managers(119071)
3770    Patternmakers Metal and Plastic(514062)
3710    Wind Turbine Service Technicians(499081)
3650    Embalmers(394011)
3640    Rail Transportation Workers All Other(534099)
3630    Rock Splitters Quarry(475051)
3620    Home Economics Teachers Postsecondary(251192)
3620    Commercial Divers(499092)
3570    Paperhangers(472142)
3550    Shoe Machine Operators and Tenders(516042)
3470    Pile-Driver Operators(472072)
3380    Transit and Railroad Police(333052)
3280    Manufactured Building and Mobile Home Installers(499095)
3280    Bridge and Lock Tenders(536011)
3250    Terrazzo Workers and Finishers(472053)
3220    Historians(193093)
3150    Camera and Photographic Equipment Repairers(499061)
3130    Mathematicians(152021)
3090    Travel Guides(397012)
2840    Hoist and Winch Operators(537041)
2780    Log Graders and Scalers(454023)
2730    Logging Workers All Other(454029)
2660    Miscellaneous Mathematical Science Occupations(152090)
2630    Mine Shuttle Car Operators(537111)
2610    Makeup Artists Theatrical and Performance(395091)
2470    Mining Machine Operators All Other(475049)
2450    Agricultural Engineers(172021)
2390    Watch Repairers(499064)
2370    Communications Equipment Operators All Other(432099)
2350    Animal Scientists(191011)
2310    Model Makers and Patternmakers Wood(517030)
2240    Sociologists(193041)
2180    Genetic Counselors(299092)
1900    Dredge Operators(537031)
1850    Forestry and Conservation Science Teachers Postsecondary(251043)
1730    Refractory Materials Repairers Except Brickmasons(499045)
1660    Astronomers(192011)
1650    Timing Device Assemblers and Adjusters(512093)
1630    Forest Fire Inspectors and Prevention Specialists(332022)
1610    Locomotive Firers(534012)
1600    Mathematical Science Occupations All Other(152099)
1360    Model Makers Wood(517031)
1260    Geographers(193092)
1130    Segmental Pavers(474091)
1110    Industrial-Organizational Psychologists(193032)
1110    Animal Breeders(452021)
1100    Radio Operators(274013)
1060    Mathematical Technicians(152091)
950 Farm Labor Contractors(131074)
950 Patternmakers Wood(517032)
710 Fabric Menders Except Garment(499093)
630 Prosthodontists(291024)
560 Cooks Private Household(352013)
560 Fishing and Hunting Workers(453000)
400 Fishers and Related Fishing Workers(453011)
```

Answer (score 0):

Carers, for the children and the elderly. Note that carer involves some kind of human to human relationship; a robot would not do.